# To find the limit of $x^{2017}$ by definition

Tags: calculus, limits

How do you compute the derivative of $f(x)=x^{2017}$ by definition?

$$f'(a)=\lim_{h\rightarrow a}\frac{h^{2017}-a^{2017}}{h-a}=\lim_{h\rightarrow a} (hhhh...hhh+hahh...hhh+haha...hhh+hahaha...hhh+hahahaha...hhh+hahahahaha...hhh+hahahahahaha...hhh+hahahahahahaha...hhh+hahahahahahahaha...hhh+hahahahahahahahaha...hhh+hahahahahahahahahaha...hhh+...+...aaaaaaaaaahaha+aaaaaa...aaaaaha+aaa...aaa)$$

I cannot stop laughing when I see so many haha in simplified expression, can someone help me?

Comment: Given the season you should be finding $f^\prime(0)$.

Comment: Just use the binomial theorem to expand $\frac{(x+h)^{2017}-x^{2017}}{h}$, all of the limits go to $0$ except $\frac{2017hx^{2016}}{h}$, the limit of this expression when $h$ goes to $0$ is clearly $2017x^{2016}$

Comment: Hahahahahahahahah

Comment: This "question" shouldn't be closed. It has to be taken as it is: mathematical humor (btw, hard to catch if you are not mathematically inclined).

Comment: Call in the damn factor police quickly. Premature celebration. Not allowed.

Comment: "can someone help me?" help you stop laughing or help you solve the question?

Comment: I think you should evaluate the limit at 'o' as well?

Comment: I put in my elector vote.

Comment: What is funny in $$\sum_{k=0}^{2016}h^ka^{2016-k}\to\sum_{k=0}^{2016}a^ka^{2016-k}=2017a^{2016}\ ?$$

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x) = x^{2017}$, then at any number $a$ we can write $$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^{2017}-a^{2017}}{x-a}$$ $$=\lim_{x \to a} \frac{(x-a)(x^{2016} + x^{2015}a+x^{2014}a^2+\cdots a^{2016})}{x-a}$$ $$= 2017a^{2016}$$